# How to let each instance call to have it is own boolean value?

Tags: python

I have a list of cars and their mileage in meters (I get the data's from an game API but I will use a function example instead here.) So every car has a **started = false** at the beginning and have a function which will return if they started and driven over 1 meter.

```
metersdriven = 0
started = False

def getCarState(id):
    if id == 1:
        return 290
    if id == 2:
        return 0
    if id == 3:
        return 1200


def init(driver):
    global metersdriven, started       

    metersdriven = getCarState(driver)    

    if not started:
        if metersdriven > 1:
            started = True
            return metersdriven
        else:
            return 'Not started'
    else:    
        return 'Not started'
```

That is the code and here is what I mean:

```
fd = init(1)
sd = init(2)
td = init(3)

>>> print(fd)
290

>>> print(sd)
'Not started'
```

As you can see above we have not still got a problem, however a problem comes now

```
>>> print(td)
'Not started'
```

We actually wanted to check the third car but it returned **'Not started'** which isn't true, it has actually being driven 1200 meters.

I can understand it is being caused by when we initially called to check the first car and thus made the **started to True**. If we were to call the third car at first, it will have returned 1200 meters and vice versa.

So how can I solve this? how do I make each car to have it is own boolean value? do I need to use class?

Comment: How do you "start" a car? It's not clear to me what purpose the `started` flag even serves. Can you just delete it entirely along with the `if not started` check?

Comment: Is all this code supposed to be in a class?

Comment: You probably want to make this object-oriented instead - having car objects with the class variable metersdriven and a class method started() which returns True if metersdriven > 0.

The problem in your code is that you seem to try to mix global and local variables.

Comment: John Kugelman i mentioned the purpose, I get them from a game api and so each starts at false

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use classes for this as it will allow you to easily manage instances. Something like the following would suffice:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, mileage):
        self.mileage = mileage
        self.started = False

    def start(self):
        self.started = True if self.mileage > 0 else False
    def stop(self):
        self.started = False
```

Now make an instance like so:

```
>>> sd = Car(1200) # 1200 is the mileage
>>> fd = Car(0)    # this one has 0 mileage
>>> sd.started
False
>>> sd.start()
>>> sd.started
True
>>> fd.start()
>>> fd.started
False # because mileage is 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the `started` variable all together and use only the meters driven to check if the car has run.